# Make an absolute path using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and going up folder levels ie ../includes/?

Tags: php

SOLVED.

Is there any way to set an absolute path such as:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '../../includes/blah.php';
```

That's the code I tried and it looks for this:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs../../includes/blah.php"
```

Obviously not working the way I was hoping it would. Is there a way to modify it to work, or is it simply not possible?

I feel quite foolish, but this works:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../../includes/blah.php';
```

Yay me I guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a slash

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../../includes/blah.php';
```

Fixed!